# Device to Device push notification using android gcm without third party server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We are planning to wirte a messaging/chat kind applicaiton on Android.We are planning to use GCM to exchange messages.The traditional way is to have a Application Server to store all the gcmid of the users and if  user1 wants to send message to user2,

1.The user1 send the message to Application server  with payload which contains message and receipent id i.e user2 
2.The application server retrieves the gcmid of user2 and call sender.send(regid2 , message)
3.User2 receives the message.

I see it is just a REST API Call to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send.

So if somhow user1 has the gcmid of user2 why can't we directly call the gcm API from user1 device to reduce the load on server and cost of operations on server.Pls advise me on this.

Note:We are not planning to use Upstreaming

Comment: did you solved your issue ? can you send data to another android without use of server ?

Answer (score 1):

i did the same using [Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example](http://androidexample.com/Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=122&aaid=142) tutorial. this tut is having complate sever as well as client code using gcm. go through it,will help you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the info.We were able to do push through the device directly without server.My query is abt to enquire whether it is approporiate to do that way and do u forsee any problems in future

Comment: ahhh,too much limitation of using this,because you can't send more than 4kb data.push notifications takes time even.and also you cant trasfer file like audio,video,images.etc.

Comment: the example you have suggested is still using server. how does this solves the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> So **if somehow** user1 has the gcmid of user2 ...

I think this is precisely where the difficulty lies. If you call directly the GCM API from the device, you need to transfer the gcmid from one device to the others, and by far the simplest and scalable solution I can think of is to use a server, reachable from every devices.

Comment: I would like to store gcm of all user friends on device to reduce the server dependency and hence reducing the daily maintainence cost of GAE in which we are planning to run the server..So i would like to know whether it is right way to do gcm call directly from android device